# Ambari Spark2 installation failed on Ubunut 16.04 with 'E: Unable to locate package spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187'

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu-16.04, ambari, apache-spark-2.0

Tried installing Install Spark2 History Server from Ambari UI

stderr:

```
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/SPARK2/package/scripts/job_history_server.py", line 102, in <module>
    JobHistoryServer().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 352, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/SPARK2/package/scripts/job_history_server.py", line 42, in install
    self.install_packages(env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 849, in install_packages
    retry_count=agent_stack_retry_count)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/packaging.py", line 30, in action_install
    self._pkg_manager.install_package(package_name, self.__create_context())
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/repo_manager/apt_manager.py", line 35, in wrapper
    return function_to_decorate(self, name, *args[2:], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/repo_manager/apt_manager.py", line 279, in install_package
    shell.repository_manager_executor(cmd, self.properties, context, env=self.properties.install_cmd_env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/shell.py", line 753, in repository_manager_executor
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Failed to execute command '/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef --allow-unauthenticated --assume-yes install spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187', exited with code '100', message: 'E: Unable to locate package spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187
'
```

stdout:

```
2019-12-24 14:48:57,890 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster Stack=3.0, Command Stack=None, Command Version=None -> 3.0
2019-12-24 14:48:57,894 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/conf
2019-12-24 14:48:57,895 - Group['livy'] {}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,896 - Group['ubuntu'] {}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,896 - Group['spark'] {}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,896 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,897 - User['livy'] {'gid': 'ubuntu', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['livy', 'ubuntu'], 'uid': None}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,897 - User['ubuntu'] {'gid': 'ubuntu', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['ubuntu'], 'uid': None}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,898 - User['spark'] {'gid': 'ubuntu', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['ubuntu', 'spark'], 'uid': None}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,898 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,899 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ubuntu /tmp/hadoop-ubuntu,/tmp/hsperfdata_ubuntu,/home/ubuntu,/tmp/ubuntu,/tmp/sqoop-ubuntu 0'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ubuntu) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,921 - Group['ubuntu'] {}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,922 - User['ubuntu'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['ubuntu', u'ubuntu']}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,922 - FS Type: HDFS
2019-12-24 14:48:57,922 - Directory['/etc/hadoop'] {'mode': 0755}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,933 - File['/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'ubuntu', 'group': 'ubuntu'}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,934 - Directory['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir'] {'owner': 'ubuntu', 'group': 'ubuntu', 'mode': 01777}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,947 - Repository['HDP-3.0-repo-1'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu16/3.x/updates/3.0.1.0', 'action': ['prepare'], 'components': [u'HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': '{{package_type}} {{base_url}} {{components}}', 'repo_file_name': 'ambari-hdp-1', 'mirror_list': None}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,951 - Repository with url http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-GPL/ubuntu16/3.x/updates/3.0.1.0 is not created due to its tags: set([u'GPL'])
2019-12-24 14:48:57,951 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22-repo-1'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22/repos/ubuntu16', 'action': ['prepare'], 'components': [u'HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '{{package_type}} {{base_url}} {{components}}', 'repo_file_name': 'ambari-hdp-1', 'mirror_list': None}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,952 - Repository[None] {'action': ['create']}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,954 - File['/tmp/tmpv32KZc'] {'content': 'deb http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu16/3.x/updates/3.0.1.0 HDP main\ndeb http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22/repos/ubuntu16 HDP-UTILS main'}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,954 - Writing File['/tmp/tmpv32KZc'] because contents don't match
2019-12-24 14:48:57,954 - File['/tmp/tmpaUg0V6'] {'content': StaticFile('/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari-hdp-1.list')}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,955 - Writing File['/tmp/tmpaUg0V6'] because contents don't match
2019-12-24 14:48:57,955 - Package['unzip'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:57,993 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
2019-12-24 14:48:57,994 - Package['curl'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,028 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
2019-12-24 14:48:58,029 - Package['hdp-select'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,063 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select
2019-12-24 14:48:58,067 - The repository with version 3.0.1.0-187 for this command has been marked as resolved. It will be used to report the version of the component which was installed
2019-12-24 14:48:58,214 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/conf
2019-12-24 14:48:58,223 - Package['spark2-3-0-1-0-187'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,261 - Skipping installation of existing package spark2-3-0-1-0-187
2019-12-24 14:48:58,261 - Package['spark2-3-0-1-0-187-python'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,295 - Skipping installation of existing package spark2-3-0-1-0-187-python
2019-12-24 14:48:58,296 - Package['livy2-3-0-1-0-187'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,322 - Skipping installation of existing package livy2-3-0-1-0-187
2019-12-24 14:48:58,322 - Package['spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-12-24 14:48:58,357 - Installing package spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187 ('/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef --allow-unauthenticated --assume-yes install spark-atlas-connector-3-0-1-0-187')
2019-12-24 14:49:30,887 - The repository with version 3.0.1.0-187 for this command has been marked as resolved. It will be used to report the version of the component which was installed

Command failed after 1 tries
```

Ambari: HDP-3.0.1.0

Ubuntu 16.04

repo: http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu16/2.x/updates/2.7.4.0 Ambari main

Its fails all the times when trying to install from ambari UI.

Is there any ways to run this successfully or any alternative ways to overcome this issue.

Do i miss anything to check or configure?

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? I do have exactly the same problem

Comment: @Depa I didn't find a fix for this but I could install the stacks successfully by using different version url.